# What happens to the mind of a recipient of a Jedi mind trick?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

I was reading about Jedi mind tricks and am curious to know what happens to the mind of the subject afterward. On Wookieepedia it says:

> Should the trick succeed, he or she then agreed to whatever was being said to them without being able to think for themselves. Moments later, they would feel puzzled about their new opinion, but usually didn't feel like changing it back.

So if a Jedi was to, say, trick someone into giving the Jedi money (or whatever), would the person later just think to himself, "I gave that Jedi 10 grand but whatever"? Of course we're ignoring the fact that Jedi shouldn't use these things for personal gain (and that they don't use USD).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The beauty of a mind trick is that the recipient is not aware of being tricked. Anyway, it wouldn't work otherwise. They think their change of mind is genuine and don't feel the need to re-question it.

A example is [Elan Sel'Sabagno](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Elan_Sel%27Sabagno), the drug dealer Obi-Wan mind-tricked to "go home and rethink [his] life".

> After being mind tricked by Obi-Wan in the Outlander Club, he went home and completely rethought his life. He managed to break his death stick addiction and swore off the slythmonger business, but soon enough slipped back into his old criminal ways [...]

The mind-trick was enough to put him in a new mid-state, he thought the idea to rethink [his] life came from him and didn't attribute it to Obi-Wan, but this was not enough to change his personality.

---

So if a Jedi trick someone into giving him money, this person would just think "I gave that Jedi 10 grand because ..." and will justify this action himself, like we do when we take a decision on a whim. Depending on his personalty, it could be "because I'm so generous", "because was good for my reputation" or "because he was cute".

Answer (score 2):

In Scourge, Mander Zuma explains to Toro's sister, that the mind trick could have severe adverse effects, such as whenever the target was aroung the caster, they would feel troubled, because they knew something went wrong around them. Therefore Jedi only used this power on beings they thought they would never encounter again.