# For how long do the effects of a Jedi Mind Trick last?

Tags: star-wars

Some commands can be followed instantly. For example, if a Jedi commands a weak-minded person using Force to reveal certain information, he/she can do that instantly ending the temporal scope of the command.

But, what happens when the temporal scope of command is long? For example, a Jedi commands a stormtrooper to kill Vader after 10 years. Or, a Jedi told a stormtrooper that rebels are his friends.

Do the effects of a Jedi Mind Trick last forever? Or, is this just like hypnosis and after some time, the affected person can snap out of it?

Comment: I think that guy went home and rethought his life

Comment: @Valorum Do we actually know the guy with the deathsticks actually did that? Any quotes to back this up?

Comment: @Loki will you be surprised if Valorum *does* know the guy?

Comment: @Verdan - Ask it as a question and ye shall be enlightened

Comment: @Valorum Actually I found the answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16334/84000 so asking again would be a dupe. And yeah, you're right once again :)